# Why LiveData observer execute when value changed before set observer?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I test `LiveData` like this.

```kotlin
// MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    val testViewModel: TestViewModel by viewModels()
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        testViewModel.testLiveData.value = true
        testViewModel.testLiveData.observe(this) {
            println("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// TestViewModel.kt
class TestViewModel : ViewModel(){
    val testLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    
}
```

I think.... `(livedata).observe` mean start observe about liveData value change.
I don't think the value changed before the observer is set is not observable.
But, it print `hello`....
Am I misunderstood about live data observers?

Comment: `LiveData` is meant to represent an observable state: when there's a value, it will be emitted every time an observer starts observing.

Comment: I tested code `testViewModel.testLiveData.value = null`.
That code run the observer. 
It has no value, but runs the observer. Why...?

Comment: LiveData counts `null` as a value. There's no way to clear a LiveData. You can create a new instance of the LiveData instead. But if you need to do this, you probably have a design problem or don't understand something about lifecycles.

Comment: I didn't think LiveData would consider null as a value too....
I would like to see the code when the value of LiveData changes. Can you give me some advice on where to look?

Comment: You want to look at the source code of LiveData?

Comment: The current design is that the 2 fragments share 1 viewmodel and move the screen when the live data changes.

I've heard that you should use `SingleLiveData`, `Event wrapper` when moving the screen.
But since we are observing it with viewLifeCycleOwner, it will be onDestroyView when the screen is moved.
So I thought it wouldn't affect other fragments, but as soon as I observe it, it runs and there is a problem.

Comment: Yes. I want to look source code about how to notify livedata change to own observers.

Comment: You can subclass MutableLiveData and override `setValue` to do something extra when the value is changed. I don't really understand what you're trying to do though. Seems like LiveData is not the right tool for the job. [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) is a hack but might be what you want . Today it can be  replaced with SharedFlow with replay=0, which I think is a more sensible solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will search about  `Shared Flow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start observing a LiveData, if the LiveData has a value already, it will replay that value to the observer immediately. This is by design, because LiveData is typically in a ViewModel that outlives the views. For example, when the screen rotates, all the views are recreated and observations begin again. All the views will be updated with the latest values of the LiveData. If it didn't behave this way, then when the screen rotates and Activities/Fragments are recreated, they would just sit there and have nothing to observe, defeating the purpose of using a ViewModel to retain state that outlives views.